# How maven ci friendly bump up version in pom and prevent snapshot deploy

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, maven-release-plugin

We are using maven release plugin to build deployable. While maven release plugin is slow as it does several things. There is an alternative way in maven from maven 3.5.0. Its maven ci friendly feature https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

But two things I don't understand.

- How does we bump up next development version in pom.xml using ci friendly plugin. It is performed by DdevelopmentVersion flag of maven-release-plugin. Does the version stay same forever in pom.xml and we upgrade version from command line only ?
- How does maven ci friendly prevent deploying snapshot artifact for production. Which maven-release-plugin does by default.

Any clarification would be highly appreciated.

Comment: First there is no ci friendly plugin. Second if you like to change the version you simple change the command line from `mvn -Drevision=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT clean package` into `mvn -Drevision=2.0.0-SNAPSHOT clean package`. You don't use the release plugin at all. And to bump the verison you can simply change the property in the pom file.. that's it...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I automate version changing ? I don't want to do manual commit. Second question was what's the way to avoid snapshot version for production. Release plugin has this feature.